# How to add "Or" or "OrElse" in MakeComparison

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a method for dynamic creating a query. This works fine. But I also want to add "Or" or "OrElse". I have searched the internet but can't find an example. I would be also nice to have also an "in" in the query.
When I try "or" or "OrElse" I see in the logfile that it put an "And" and not an "Or".

I also get this error: The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable1[System.Int16]' and 'System.Nullable1[System.Int16

```
private static Expression MakeComparison(Expression left, string comparison, string value)
{
    switch (comparison)
    {
        case "==":
        case "IsEqualTo":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, value);
        case "!=":
        case "IsNotEqualTo":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, left, value);
        case ">":
        case "IsGreaterThan":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, left, value);
        case ">=":
        case "IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, left, value);
        case "<":
        case "IsLessThan":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThan, left, value);
        case "<=":
        case "IsLessThanOrEqualTo":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, left, value);
        case "OrElse":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, left, value);
        case "Or":
            return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Or, left, value);
        case "Contains":
        case "StartsWith":
        case "EndsWith":
            return Expression.Call(MakeString(left), comparison, Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)));
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{comparison}'.");
    }

    private static Expression MakeBinary(ExpressionType type, Expression left, string value)
    {
        object typedValue = value;
        if (left.Type != typeof(string))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                typedValue = null;
                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) == null)
                    left = Expression.Convert(left, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type));
            }
            else
            {
                var valueType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) ?? left.Type;
                typedValue = valueType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(valueType, value) :
                    valueType == typeof(Guid) ? Guid.Parse(value) :
                    Convert.ChangeType(value, valueType);
            }
        }
        var right = Expression.Constant(typedValue, left.Type);
        return Expression.MakeBinary(type, left, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have using `OrElse`?

Comment: I don't get it to work. I have used "Or" or "OrElse", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include what you tried, and what made you think it didn't work?

Comment: I have edited the question and the code

Comment: _“it doesn't work”_ is not a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Comment: What's the C# equivalent to the code you're trying to generate? I can understand `MakeComparison(x, "==", "Foo")` turning into `x == "Foo"`, but what C# code is `MakeComparison(x, "Or", "Foo")` supposed to turn into?

Comment: I want a query which gave me the folowing: X == "Foo" And (Y == 1 Or Y ==2)

Comment: OK, so how are you passing in the `Y == 2` bit, given that your `value` is a `string`, not an `Expression`?

Comment: I have pasted the code MakeBinary. The Y==2 is passed as a expression. It's a generic function

Comment: I also get this error: The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int16

Comment: Are you trying to construct an equivalent of `3 || 4`? Because that isn't valid C#

Comment: No, I'm want a query that looks like X == "Foo" And (Y == 1 Or Y == 2)

Comment: So, again, how are you trying to pass something which is more complex than a single value through that `value` parameter, which is just a string? It looks like you're trying to call `MakeComparison(Expression.Constant(3), "OrElse", "4")` or similar, which is going to try and compile `3 || 4` which obviously isn't valid code

Comment: In other words, `Expression.OrElse` takes **expressions** for the left and right parameters, But you've only got a way of passing a single **value** for the right parameter. This is OK for things like comparisons but fairly useless for `||`, unless you want to restrict yourself to writing `<expression> || true` and `<expression> || false`

Comment: That Or or OrElse shouldn't work on a (string) 'value', but on two (boolean-returning) Expressions

Comment: This is the method to build the predicate:  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
                {
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                    var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
                    var body = MakeComparison(left, comparison, value);
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                }

Comment: I don't think you're listening to me, unfortunately. You're trying to build an expression of the form `left || value`, where `left` can be any value but `value` is a simple constant. `||` needs both sides to be bools, which means the only things you can compile are `left || true` and `left || false`. Both of those are useless. You need `value` to be an **expression** not a **string**

Comment: Oke. i'll try setting a expression in value. i'll let you know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Canton7, sorry for late reaction.  The problem is been solved. Thanks very much for your patient and answers.